# Linear Programming using R - Error in SolveLP

Tags: r, optimization, linear-programming

This my R code:

```
#install.packages("linprog")
library(linprog)


roi=c(0.04,0.02,0.03,0.11,0.03,0.2,0.17,0.24,0.03,0.04,0.04)

bvet=c(100000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

Amat=rbind(

c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),  
c(0.96,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04),
  c(-0.02,0.98,-0.02,-0.02,-0.02,-0.02,-0.02,-0.02,-0.02,-0.02,-0.02),
  c(-0.03,-0.03,0.97,-0.03,-0.03,-0.03,-0.03,-0.03,-0.03,-0.03,-0.03),
  c(-0.11,-0.11,-0.11,0.89,-0.11,-0.11,-0.11,-0.11,-0.11,-0.11,-0.11),
  c(-0.03,-0.03,-0.03,-0.03,0.97,-0.03,-0.03,-0.03,-0.03,-0.03,-0.03),
  c(-0.2,-0.2,-0.2,-0.2,-0.2,0.8,-0.2,-0.2,-0.2,-0.2,-0.2),
  c(-0.17,-0.17,-0.17,-0.17,-0.17,-0.17,0.83,-0.17,-0.17,-0.17,-0.17),
  c(-0.24,-0.24,-0.24,-0.24,-0.24,-0.24,-0.24,0.83,-0.24,-0.24,-0.24),
  c(-0.03,-0.03,-0.03,-0.03,-0.03,-0.03,-0.03,0.97,-0.03,-0.03,-0.03),
  c(-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,0.96,-0.04),
  c(-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,-0.04,0.96)
)

LP=solveLP(roi,bvet,Amat,TRUE)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in solveLP(roi, bvet, Amat, TRUE) : 
  Matrix A must have as many rows as constraints (=elements of vector b) and as many columns as variables (=elements of vector c).
```

I checked my code a number of times and the same issue persists.

Comment: Check the number of rows of `Amat` with the number of elements of `bvet`...

Comment: There are 12 rows in `Amat`, but 11 entries in  both `bvet` and `roi`. This cannot work.

Comment: But in "Amat" cant i use Different no. of constraints?

Comment: Thanks Rhertel...It worked!!